# ruby: converting from float to integer in ruby produces strange results

Tags: ruby, floating-accuracy

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :003 > (10015.8*100.0).to_i
 => 1001579 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :004 > 10015.8*100.0
 => 1001580.0 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :005 > 1001580.0.to_i
 => 1001580
```

ruby 1.8.7 produces the same.
Does anybody knows how to eradicate this heresy? =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, all of this make sense.

Because ***0.8*** cannot be represented exactly by any series of *`1 / 2 ** x`* for various *`x`*, it must be represented approximately, and it happens that this is slightly less than ***10015.8.***

So, when you just print it, it is rounded reasonably.

When you convert it to an integer without adding ***0.5,*** it truncates ***.79999999...*** to ***.7***

When you type in ***10001580.0,*** well, that has an *exact* representation in all formats, including float and double. So you don't see the truncation of a value ever so slightly less than the next integral step.

Floating point is not inaccurate, it just has limitations on what can be represented. Yes, FP is *perfectly accurate* but cannot necessarily represent every number we can easily type in using base ***10.*** (Update/clarification: well, ironically, it can represent exactly every integer, because every integer has a ***`2 ** x`*** composition, but "every fraction" is another story. Only certain decimal fractions can be exactly composed using a ***`1/2**x`*** series.)

In fact, JavaScript implementations use floating point storage and arithmetic for all numeric values. This is because FP hardware produces exact results for integers, so this got the JS guys 52-bit math using existing hardware on (at the time) almost-entirely 32-bit machines.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought I could hit any of the accuracy problems on such a small numbers.

Comment: @Hitosu Nothing to do with small number. It is the way computers deals with floating point numbers.

Comment: @Hitosu: It's not so much an accuracy problem as it is a *representation* problem. Floats are represented in the source code in decimal but in RAM in binary. This means that numbers which *look like* they should have a finite representation (i.e. in your case `4/5`) actually have an *infinite* representation (IOW: no matter *how* accurate you make your floats, you still would get rounding errors). The problem is that there is a cognitive disconnect between what you see and what you get: you wouldn't be surprised at all that `1/3` has an infinite representation, but for `1/10` it's not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Due to truncation error in float calculation, 10015.8*100.0 is actually calculated as 1001579.999999... So if you simply apply to_i, it cuts off the decimal part and returns 1001579

Comment: I had the same problem, if you multiply with 100 and convert to integer the last digit is wrong, (149.45*100).to_i gives 14944, but (149.45*100).round is 14945.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

```
>> sprintf("%.16f", 10015.8*100.0)
=> "1001579.9999999999000000"
```

And `Float#to_i` truncates this to 1001579.