# Get Price in Cents for Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have to send the amount of some price in cents to [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) in order to make charge against a card. In my app, the `total_price` value is a decimal, i.e in dollars and cents. Obviously, I can convert this to cents by multiplying by 100:

```
total_price * 100
```

But the result is still a decimal, and Stripe gives me an 'Invalid amount' error. I know there can be issues with rounding floats. I want to know the safest way to cast my `total_price` to an integer in Rails. I have seen some reference to a money gem but is this necessary in this case?

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255629/ruby-converting-from-float-to-integer-in-ruby-produces-strange-results

Comment: Is `total_price` really a decimal, or is it a float?

Comment: So `to_i` is the correct solution? @andrew - to be honest I'm not sure (like I say learning RoR) I think it's a decimal - it is in the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby has several methods available to floats, depending on what you need:

- `(cart.total_price * 100).to_i (discards all decimals)`
- `(cart.total_price * 100).round # .round(numofdecimals)`
- `(cart.total_price * 100).floor # 1.3 => 1`
- `(cart.total_price * 100).ceil  # 1.3 => 2`
- `(cart.total_price * 100).to_r #to rationals, e.g. 2.5 => 5/2`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think `to_r` would be helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a very easy way to do this, directly from a decimal without converting to a float first.  Given:

`decimal price = BigDecimal('100.00')`

You can use BigDecimal's fix() and frac() methods to take the first part, multiply by 100 and add the fraction:

`price_in_cents = ((decimal_price.fix * 100) + decimal_price.frac).to_i`

Another seemingly simple possibility is to use string manipulation.  You can convert the decimal to a string, strip the period, and convert to integer like:

`price_in_cents = decimal_price.to_s.sub('.', '').to_i`

But the gotcha here is that decimal_price.to_s == '100.0' not '100.00'.  If there are non-zero digits in the fraction, then they would be preserved in the conversion, but otherwise one is lost.  So if decimal_price == 111.11 then the above string manipulation would return the expected result.